# Form validation not running onsubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, function, onsubmit

I am trying to run a form validation on an HTML form to make sure the person has filled out the two fields. I put together a JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yCqqj/

It has worked previously for me and I don't know what's going on now. I made a JSFiddle to pull it out of my site to make sure nothing else was conflicting with it but I'm realizing now that it's something in the code. The two fields are name "emailaddress" and "Name" respectively and it looks like I'm checking their values correctly. Basically, I'm looking for an alert (and NOT a submittal of the form) if they've left either field blank. Thanks for helping me track down the problem. I appreciate it.

```
function ValidateForm(){
    var emailID=document.MailingList.emailaddress
    var nameID=document.MailingList.Name

        if ((nameID.value==null)||(nameID.value=="")){
        alert("Please Enter your Name");
        nameID.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if ((emailID.value==null)||(emailID.value=="")){
        alert("Please Enter your Email ID");
        emailID.focus();
        return false;
    }
 }
```

​
Even though there is not return true, the form still submits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is that you haven't defined ValidateForm in the `Head` section.
i have edited the jsfiddle.check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yCqqj/1/).

Comment: Are you saying it should be within the `<head>` tags on the page? I've tried that on the page itself and for some reason it doesn't work still? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Hmm, yeah that worked: http://jsfiddle.net/yCqqj/2/ . I may have to check for conflicts on the page maybe?

Comment: i saw in the developer tool that error happens because ValidateForm could not be found.i just have moved it to head tag and it solved.

Comment: yeah developer tool / firebug is very useful for debugging, below is from chrome:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: ValidateForm is not defined"

Comment: I am wondering if it is conflicting with something else on the page. Are you using Firefox or Chrome to check the Javascript?

Comment: i use firefox.why u don't use Jquery?

Comment: I can't find a script that will work correctly with the page I'm on. There seems to be all sorts of conflict. I'm just trying to find the simplest way to check if both fields are filled out. In the code I used, there's also a problem where if you fill out the name and leave the e-mail blank, the rest of the validation doesn't work either. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I'm worried that taking the time to learn all the jQuery code and then put it in the page is going to yield the same results. If I have correct code (which I do now, thank you!) and I insert it into the page and it doesn't work, I guess I haven't really figured out the problem....

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problem:

First, what is echeck? If I take that code away it will work.
Second you should not do return after your control of the nameID.value. If you do that your control of the emailID.value will not be done.

Comment: Won't it submit the form if I don't do a return even if it's false?

Comment: If you return false the form will not be submited. As soon as you return true it will be submited.

Comment: Right so it would first check for the name. If the name was there then it would check for the e-mail. If the e-mail was there then it would return true, correct? Or do I have that wrong?

Comment: If think you script should look something like this: function ValidateForm(){
    var emailID=document.MailingList.emailaddress
    var nameID=document.MailingList.Name

        if ((nameID.value==null)||(nameID.value=="")){
        alert("Please Enter your Name")
        nameID.focus()
        return false
    }
       
    if ((emailID.value==null)||(emailID.value=="")){
        alert("Please Enter your Email ID")
        emailID.focus()
        return false
    }
    
    return true
 }

Comment: That didnt look good... You should only do return true at the last line in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I just updated the code. It works on JSFiddle but I can't get it to work on the page. I don't know...

Comment: Ok, so you dont want the form to submit even if the values in the inputs are correct?

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback on Behnam's answer, it is because ValidateForm isn't defined in the head section as he said. But here's how to fix it:

In jsfiddle, in the upper left area in Frameworks & Extensions, set it to no-wrap . Then update and set as base to save your changes.

[image]